# If $G$ is $k$-transitive but not $(k+1)$-transitive, is it true that $G$ is sharply $k$-transitive?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, examples-counterexamples

There is an exercise:

> If $G$ is $k$-transitive but not $(k+1)$-transitive, is it true that $G$ is sharply $k$-transitive?

I solved this exercise:

> If $G$ is sharply $k$-transitive then $G$ is not $(k+1)$-transitive.

I try to prove the first exercise. But I don't have any idea how to solve it. I don't know if it's true or false. I think it's false but which counterexample?

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated. Thanks to everyone for the help.

Comment: It's false. There is an counterexample in Mathieu groups.

Comment: Three out of five Mathieu groups are counterexamples, indeed, but there is a way easier one in $S_4$.

Comment: This is false for all $k \ge 1$. It has been proved (by Marshall Hall I think) that the only sharply $k$-transitive groups for $k \ge 4$ are $M_{11}$ with $k=4$, $M_{12}$ with $k=5$, $A_{k+2}$ and $S_k$.

Comment: I think I have seen that result being credited to Jordan, somewhere.

Comment: This is **Exercise 7.1.3** of Robinson's, *"A Course in the Theory of Groups (Second Edition)"*.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, there is a counterexample among Mathieu groups (for instance $M_{24}$ is a $5$-transitive group of degree $24$ which is easily seen to be neither $6$-transitive nor sharply $5$-transitive), but there is a way simpler example.

Consider in $S_4$ the subgroup $H=\langle (12)(34),(13) \rangle$, which is of order $8$. $H$ is clearly $1$-transitive since it contains the Klein $4$-group of $S_4$, which is transitive. Moreover, the transitivity of $H$ is not sharp because of its order. Finally, $H$ is not $2$-transitive, as the only proper $2$-transitive subgroup of $S_4$ is $A_4$.

Comment: How can you prove that the only proper 2-transitive group of $S_4$ is $A_4$?

Comment: You could use the fact that a $k$-transitive permutation group of degree $n$ has order divisible by $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$, which in our case is $12$.